# Synchronizing two multimedia devices on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, multimedia

I've connected two multimedia devices to my PC, the Galaxy Note 10.1 and Galaxy S3. I would like to synchronize two folders - one on the first device, one on the other. Is there a way of doing so other than copying contents of these folders to the PC?

I've tried Total Commander, but it refuses to compare directories other than local or zip. On the other hand, Windowses copy mechanism is not smart enough and when I choose to skip conflicting items, it skips all folders - regardless of whether their contents match or not.

The main problem is that when I connect these devices to PC, they are displayed as "Multimedia Device" and don't get their drive letters, so I cannot use any software, which relies on this fact.

Answer (score 0):

If internet connectivity isn't an issue, you can use Dropbox or Google Drive to sync folders between devices.

Comment: The Internet connectivity itself no, but these folders are quite large (~8Gb) and that might be a problem :)